# Nativescript angular local file system images not showing

Tags: nativescript, react-native, angular2-nativescript

i have created nativescript angular app with nativescript side kick software with navigation drawer template, i want to display image in home page from local file system.

i am using latest angular and nativescript

APP

--> images

--> Home

### Local Build and Cloud Build

`<Image  src="res://icon" ></Image>` --> showing image

`<Image src="../images/intensepic.jpg"  ></Image>` --> if i click on "..images/intensepic.jpg" using ctrl+click its going to path of images in project and pick image but image is not showing in app.

`<Image src="~/images/intensepic.jpg"  ></Image>` --> if i click on "~/images/intensepic.jpg" using ctrl+click its failed find images in project and not able to pick image and image is not showing in app.

`<Image src="/app/src/images/intensepic.jpg"  ></Image>` --> if i click on "/app/src/images/intensepic.jpg" using ctrl+click its going to path of images and pick image but image is not showing in app.

### Nativescript Playgrond

`<Image  src="res://icon" ></Image>` --> showing image

`<Image src="../images/intensepic.jpg"  ></Image>` -->  image is not showing in app.

`<Image src="~/images/intensepic.jpg"  ></Image>` -->  image is showing in app.

Which platform(s) does your issue occur on?
Both
[image]

Comment: The issue was answered here  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6343

Comment: @NickIliev i tested with your example still i am not able to see the images, i posted result screen in github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6343

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as intensepic image is in images folder not in App resources, no need to use res:// 
There must be problem with image path 
try this one

```
<Image src="~/images/intensepic.jpg"></Image>
```

or

```
<Image src="~/app/images/intensepic.jpg"></Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the [doc](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/image-resources) to understand how the image path works.

`res://` - Prefix to be used if the image is placed in the iOS / Android drawable folder located inside App_Resources.

`~/` - Points to the application directory.

Between relative paths may not work here at all. If you are sure the path was correct then try running a clean build to make sure all resources are copied.

Comment: Hi Manoj, i am trying all possible ways, i am able to work with resource imamges '(res://)' and http image url's but not with file system images '(~/)'

Comment: If you are using webpack, by default the build process will copy all image to app resources and will not be available inside app folder.

Comment: Hi Manoj, i am new to nativescript, can you please provide more info on your comment about webpack build, i am using sidekick to build app and not using webpack build option, can you please provide code for display image with webpack and with out webpack build. i added my source code and result image in my question.

Comment: It's advised to use webpack for better performance and smaller package size, SideKick is just a GUI tool, internally it's just going to relay on NativeScript CLI to build the app. Read more about webpack here - https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack I guess using `res://` should not be a problem for you.